# UIView subclass: drawRect not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am a beginner in iOS programming, so sorry if my question is a stupid question.

I am trying to make an app which performs custom drawing on a loaded image.

To do it, I found out that a solution is to subclass `UIView` and edit the `drawRect` method.

I made that on the following code which activates on an `IBAction` linked to a button in the Interface Builder storyboard file.

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:     @"SampleImage.jpg"]]; 
image.frame = previewView.frame;
[image setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];       

[previewView addSubview:image];

customView *aCustomView = [[customView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(image.bounds.origin.x, image.bounds.origin.y, image.bounds.size.width, image.bounds.size.height)];
[previewView addSubview:aCustomView];
```

`customView` is the `UIView` subclass that I created, whose `init` and `drawRect` methods are set like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"INITIALIZING");
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"DRAWING");

    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 0.3);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, rect); 

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 255, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
}
```

The problem that I have is that no drawing is made and on `NSLog` I have the "INITIALIZING" message, but not the "DRAWING" drawing.

So basically it makes the `initWithFrame`, but it doesn't call the `drawRect` method.

Could you please point me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20):

1. Make sure your new view class is subclassing the UIView, not the UIImageView.
2. To make sure the new view is showing up, you will need to do **[viewContainer addSubView:]** to get the drawRect to be called.

Ref from the doc:

> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect: a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: you can set the custom class which override the draw rect to coder

Answer (score 10):

Paolo,

Here are a few things you can try:

1. in `initWithFrame`, check that the `frame` variable contains what you
   would expect it to:
   `NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));`
2. Try calling `[preview setNeedsDisplay];` after adding it to its superview

Lastly, I would change

> image.frame = previewView.frame;

with:

> image.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, previewView.frame.size.width,
>   previewView.frame.size.height);

Comment: Thanks, by putting the NSLog I found out there was something wrong in the calling of the drawRect method. By adding the [previewView setNeedDisplay] the method is called but not when i expect it to be done. I mean, by following code steps the execution of the line [previewView setNeedDisplay] doesn't make the custom drawing appear, instead it appears later in some way. I'd like to understand in which moment the drawRect method is called but anyway the initial problem is solved, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

May be the question is aCustomView's frame is (0,0,0,0).
You can try to pass a constant CGRect param, like this : `CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 100)。`

Answer (score 1):

The answer in my case was different from all the answers I've read for similar questions, and perhaps will help someone else. It turned out that on my Storyboard, "Inherit Module From Target" was unchecked, while at the same time the Module was None. I added the checkmark and the draw method was called the next time I ran the app.